# Deployment Pipeline with Go.CD and Maven

Tags: git, maven, go-cd

So, my question is fairly simple. I want to build a pipeline with GO CD that has functional tests in a separate stage from actual building of artifacts. Similar to the picture below.
[image]

My FT Stage has multiple jobs that I want to run in parallel (using more Go agents).
But HOW do I achieve this? Because if I checkout the material (git repo) in both stages and someone commits after the first stage is triggered but before the second stage, then I brake the most important rule of CI&CD: reproducible build.

In Jenkins I tag the commit checked out at the first stage and then checkout this tag explicitly in the next job. But for some reason, Go does not support git tags :|.

I could run a task and do a "git checkout $tagname" but that's a reason for me to continue with Jenkins. It's too much of a hack

Answer (score 1):

GoCd makes sure all stages in the pipeline use the same VCS revision. You don't have to do the checkouts GoCd does it for you. Easy.